# Adding a migration in the middle of previous migrations safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a minor issue which force me to introduce a new migration in between two migrations.
Short version of my question is: whether it is safe to introduce a new migration between previous two.

**What I did**

I need to have a table which will be filled from a file. 
I added a table then imported data on the table by two migrations:

1. A migration which create a table with named ID column by using `self.primary_key = some_id`
2. A migration to import text data onto the table

The issue was, I forgot to add `:id => false` to the first migration. This cause `id` column to be created but haven't set correctly. Since I have primary key in `some_id` it does not cause problem up to now.

**Rails 3.2.4**

Now, I upgraded to Rails 3.2.4. Due to the change, it look like I need to set unique `id` before save. Which cause migration 2 above to fail.

The easiest fix is removing `id` column between above two migrations because I need test suite to build the database from scratch time to time. To make the import to work, I need to fix it before 2nd migration run.

**Question**

Now the question.

Since above migrations are deployed already, The migration will run after all of the migrations other than the one.

In my case, it looks like Ok to create such a migration (with timestamp in between above two).

Is it okay to do add migration like this way, in this case?

Comment: Why don't you undo the last transition and then write the migration that you want to go in between the last 2?

Comment: The reason is, there is tons of migrations between the second one and beyond...